# How did Mr. Incredible know how many powers Jack-Jack exhibited in Incredibles 2?

Tags: incredibles-2

At the end of *Incredibles 2*, Elastigirl was surprised by Jack-Jack's powers. Mr. Incredible said she missed his first 17 powers. However, we the audience saw these powers. He was asleep when most of the powers were displayed.

I know Edna demonstrated some of them when Mr. Incredible went to pick up Jack-Jack but there were ones he didn't see because Edna didn't demo or he was asleep, like:

1. the super strength (kicking the raccoon really far)
2. turning into putty when the raccoon tried to attack him.

So, like my title says, how did Mr. Incredible know of all 17 powers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mr. Incredible is looking after Jack-Jack 24/7 and we only ever get a small glimpse into his life with him. It stands to reason that he sees most of these powers off screen. Add to this the possibility of Edna telling him off screen as she studied Jack-Jack’s powers and it makes sense that he knows of them.